# List of all world cities with populations over 100,000

Tags: data-request, government, population

I'm making use of the [UN demographic yearbook](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/demographic/products/dyb/dyb2014/Table08.pdf) which has a table listing *most* of the world's cities with populations over 100,000 (along with their populations). However, some major places are missing, such as China and both Congos. An answer to a similar question [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1762/14414) provides a tsv file but GeoNames' population data is not too accurate (lots of outdated data and the specific sources used for each country are unknown).

Does anyone know of a list that does indeed have *all* of the world's cities with populations over 100,000 that *also* lists their population? Preferably as accurate as possible, i.e. using national census data, and relying on estimates only when necessary (and stating their source for each data point).

Comment: A SPARQL query on the Wikidata databases will probably be the most accurate and machine readable. https://query.wikidata.org/ This question is somewhat related http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/7215/1511

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Harsh's answer, here is a Wikidata SPARQL query that gives the top

[Link to Wikidata query tool](http://tinyurl.com/jlbqm3l)

[Direct link to result](http://tinyurl.com/gwgzez9)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel ?population
WHERE 
{
    ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515 .  # find instances of subclasses of city

    # Now select the population value of the ?city
    # (wdt: properties use only statements of "preferred" rank if any, usually meaning "current population")
    ?city wdt:P1082 ?population .

    # filter for cities with more than 100k
    FILTER (?population > 100000) .
    # Optionally, find English labels for city:
    SERVICE wikibase:label {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?population)
```

[image]

(adapated from [here](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#Largest_cities_with_female_mayor))

Comment: This is great, but actually I'm on a mission of sorts to update the Wikipedia [List of Cities with 100,000+ Inhabitants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_and_cities_with_100,000_or_more_inhabitants/country:_A-B) so I'm a bit wary of using Wikipedia data for that... Is this data very accurate / using official figures?

Comment: You should update your question with this info

Comment: ? The question asks for as accurate of a source as possible already, what else would I add to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a list which might be help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_largest_cities#List . You can also use wikidata(http://wikidata.org/) to query all items on wikipedia marked as cities and then their get their populations in machine readable form.

Answer (score 1):

Many small cities have merged over the years.Hence sometimes it is difficult to assign definitive values to city populations, e.g. when cites have become agglomerations - megacities. For a major fraction of the world population, this matters.

The website https://citypopulation.de/ has this data. All urban agglomerations of the world with at least 1 million inhabitants.