# Largest cities in the UK?

Tags: uk

I am looking for an up to date list of say the largest 25 cities in the UK by population.

Searching around on Google, most lists seem to be a few years outdated, and some don't even specify last updated dates. Where is the most reliable source to find an up to date list of the largest cities in the UK by population?

Example from http://www.citymayors.com/gratis/uk_topcities.html which unfortunately doesn't specify a date:

```
London  7,074,265   49.12
Birmingham  1,020,589   49.42
Leeds   726,939 49.43
Glasgow 616,430 47.73
Sheffield   530,375 49.73
...
```

There are other websites such as http://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/united-kingdom-population/cities/ which also don't specify any updated dates ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about geography, not about travel.

Comment: I am using the information, to organise travel trip. Is this travel stack exchange or not ?

Comment: @user10192176 I'd agree with Mocha Seifert. This question is likely better suited to geography, someone could ask a complicated physics question about flight on the basis that planes are used for travel, which is true. But it doesn't mean that the question wouldn't have been better placed in physics.

Comment: @user10192176 You might get less close votes if you explained why the population size matters to you. Many great places to visit in the UK possibly wouldn’t make it into the top 25 eg Chester, Warwick, while some that do (eg Wigan) might disappoint (apologies to anyone from Wigan reading this!)

Comment: geonames.org would be the first place I'd look

Comment: I closed this because it's answered at https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1762/1511 (see geonames answer)

Answer (score 2):

I wonder would the Office of National Statistics help? Their [latest population estimates](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/bulletins/annualmidyearpopulationestimates/mid2017) count as the official source and, with a bit of work to isolate precisely the area sizes etc you're interested in, they should do the trick.

Specifically, table MYE2 in the xls file linked to [on this page](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/datasets/populationestimatesforukenglandandwalesscotlandandnorthernireland).

Answer (score 1):

OCDE and European Union collect these data.
According to [this article](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php/Statistics_on_European_cities#Largest_cities_by_population) this [database](https://www.europeandataportal.eu/data/en/dataset?tags=global&country=gb) should answer your request.